# How can I read the flash device ID that is installed, perhaps via the mtd interface?

Tags: linux, drivers, embedded-linux

In our embedded Linux solution using uClinux, I have just added a larger flash device. I want to be able to query which device I have installed (hardware device).

The small and large device both have different device ID's which I can read in my device driver code.

What I don't know is how to get that information in "user land". I.e. in a shell/bash script.

I have looked at:

`cat /proc/mtd` - this gives information on the size of the partitions. But I can't tell from this, infact I will need to change the partition sizes based on which flash chip is installed.

`mtd_debug info /dev/mtd0` - This is pretty close, it tells me about the sector size (erase size), the mtd type, etc... but since the two flash chips are the same type this also is not enough info.

Comment: It looks like this is handled very differently depending on the driver and chip: Some support JEDEC READ ID, some don't, etc. Can you narrow down the possible drivers that would be used in your case?

Answer (score 1):

I have made a code-based solution to this, its in stack overflow here: [how-can-i-determine-what-mtd-flash-device-is-installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505324/how-can-i-determine-what-mtd-flash-device-is-installed)

However, since this is a code change (even if its just one-line) it does require a re-build of the kernel, so I am not marking this up as the solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

Quickly but ugly you can scan kernel output for a message about NAND:

```
dmesg | grep 'Manufacturer ID'
```

The message varies from version to version ([2.6.32](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mtd/nand/nand_base.c?v=2.6.32#L2616), [4.10](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mtd/nand/nand_base.c?v=4.10#L4153)).
Here is result for 2.6.32.57:

```
[root@board /]# dmesg | grep 'Manufacturer ID'
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0xec, Chip ID: 0xda (Samsung NAND 256MiB 3,3V 8-bit)
```

Comment: dmesg looks like a good idea - but did not work for me :( I can see the flash partitions being mounted, but I can't see any manufacturer / ID information....

Answer (score 0):

### Rreading FLASH device ID or JEDEC ID is not what you can do from Userspace.

MTD Utils package let you perform operations like erasing MTD device or copying data to
MTD device `/dev/mtdXY`.
But you cannot access internal registers and data like FLASH ID.

This FLASH ID or JEDEC ID is hardcoded on FLASH chip.
FLASH chips have special set of commands (opcodes) for various operations and can be chip specific.

So for getting this info you would need a low level SPI command with this specific opcode, which would tell your FLASH device "send me JEDEC ID number"

Usually only kernel MTD device drivers have this functionality, because they need to read FLASH ID in order to see if it matches ID numbers of FLASH chips it supports...

This is opcode to read ID from NOR SPI FLASH;

```
#define SPINOR_OP_RDID      0x9f    /* Read JEDEC ID */
```

ANd this is how command looks in kernel driver:

```
#define SPI_NOR_MAX_ID_LEN  6

tmp = nor->read_reg(nor, SPINOR_OP_RDID, id, SPI_NOR_MAX_ID_LEN);
```

So this command sends SPI data sequence to the FLASH device with known bus and CS number consisting of opcode
to read ID, and expects to receive 6 bytes long HEX number.

This `read_reg` callback further uses SPI framework function, writing one byte opcode and reading back FLASH ID:

```
ret = spi_write_then_read(spi, &code, 1, val, len);
```

So theoretically you could do the same from Userspace using right "Userspace SPI device" `spidev.X.Y` and data sequence consisting of one byte opcode and reading six bytes back.